# Shell script to compare rows in log file and display time taken for each job to complete

Tags: shell

Below I have shared my sample input:

2020/05/11 18:17:12 - job1 - Start of job execution

2020/05/11 18:17:13 - job1  - Job execution finished

2020/05/11 18:17:43 -job2- Start of job execution

2020/05/11 18:20:00 - job3- Start of job execution

2020/05/11 18:22:00 - job3- Job execution finished

2020/05/11 18:24:12 - job1 Start of job execution

2020/05/11 18:25:13 - job1 - Job execution finished

In the above input file I have to find how much time taken for each Job to complete using shell script. Below I have mentioned the expected output

Expected Output:

Job 1 ran for 1 second

Job 3 ran for 2 minutes

Job 1 ran for 1 minute and 1 second.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q is missing any code or us to help with. If you need coding services, please search the internet for "linux shell coding services for hire". AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Also, Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.